# Global number formatting in Angular?

Tags: angular

At many places in my application I want to format numbers the same. I could do it with

```
{{decimalValue | number:'3.1-5':'fr'}}
```

at every single place.

But how can I accomplish this without repeating this line for every number I want to format?

Can I define it somewhere globally? Or should I write my own pipe which knows the proper formatting? I don't want to change hundreds lines of code sometime in the future when the NFR changes...

Comment: _"should I write my own pipe"_ - sure, just compose it around the existing `NumberPipe` and have the inputs in one place.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts

You see that you can [inject the locale](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L81). So provide it with the value of your choice as a provider higher up in the hierarchy of your app and you will be able to remove this param at least (`fr`)

As for the `'3.1-5'` param, from what I see you have 2 options:

- either define this as a string in a shared file and in each of your components, declare a variable that is the same as the global one like `public NUMBER_FORMAT = NUMBER_FORMAT` when `NUMBER_FORMAT` would be imported from a shared file and defined as `const NUMBER_FORMAT: string = '3.1-5'`. Then in the HTML you could do `| number:NUMBER_FORMAT`
- Create a new number pipe of your own which extends the [original one](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L81) and where in the transform method you call `super.transform('3.1-5', 'fr')`